# Multiple activities: intent and sharedpreferences don't work between all activities

Tags: android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have an application with 3 activities let's call them A,B and C.
To switch between them, i use startactivity and it's working fine but when i want to pass data using putExtra or sharedpreferences : from A to B, there is no problem but from B to C the application crash.

Activity A

```
Intent B = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),activityB.class);
B.putExtra("adresse-ip", "192.168.1.9");
startActivity(B);
```

Activity B

```
Intent C = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),activityC.class);
C.putExtra("adresse-ip2", "abc");  //When i add this line the apllication crash
startActivity(C);
```

Even when i used sharedpreferences, i got the same problem when i read the data in activity B it works fine but when i do the same in activity C the application crash.

Comment: Can you share your AndroidManifest file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem with activity C. Make sure that Activity C is defined in AndroidManifest just like A and B; and also make sure that C is properly defined as an activity.

Comment: Yes ozo i defined activity C in AndroidManifest as follow :<activity
            android:name="activityC"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

Comment: it seems that when i add this line in activity C, there is a problem :          String adresseip2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("adresse-ip2");